# How can I run this more complicated query in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I can't seem to figure out how to run this in laravel using either the query builder or as a raw query.

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(date) as date FROM table1 group by id
) as tb1 ON tb1.id = table1.id and tb1.date = table1.date
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id 
where table2.id in(1,2,3)
```

---

Queries I've tried:

NOTE: these aren't the exact queries and they might contain errors but they represent the gist of what I tried

```
$players = \DB::select(
  'SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1
   INNER JOIN (
     SELECT id, MAX(date) as date FROM table1 group by id
   ) as tb1 ON tb1.id = table1.id and tb1.date = table1.date
   INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id where table2.id in(1,2,3)');
```

---

```
$table->select('SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1')
      ->join(\DB::raw('INNER JOIN ( SELECT id, MAX(date) as date FROM table1 group by id ) as tb1', function($join){
          $join->on('tb1id', '=', 'table1.id')->where('tb1.date','=','table1.date')
      })
      ->join('table2', function($join){
          $join->on('table2.id', '=', 'table1.id')->whereIn('table2.id',[1,2,3])
      });
```

---

So, stupid me, the first \DB::select(...) query will work, I had a debugger line in there catching queries.  I am still wondering if there
is an alternative way to do this.

Comment: Can you show us some code which you have tried already?  This is a big query.

Comment: I'll have to re-create the queries I've tried as I deleted them in frustration... but I am new to laravel so right now I'm really fighting up against the way it does things.

Comment: Yup.  It's a framework with its own way of doing things.  Post some code and you might get an answer.

Comment: why can't you run raw query for this one like DB::select() with bindings, read  http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#running-queries